# How do I create a .jar cild

Tags: java, jar

i want to do something like Jar cvf file.jar *.class but i don't see a jar compiler file in my jre6 java install. is the jar something separate i'm suppose to fine and install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic steps are (this will only package your class files into a jar (~zip) file):

1. Download the jdk from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) and install it
2. Open a terminal and go the the directory and type `jar cvf file.jar *.class`
3. Run the jar file by `java -cp file.jar your.package.MainClass`

If you want to make it directly runnable ("double-clickable" or `java -jar file.jar`) then add a manifest like [this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html).

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the JDK. That tools is included on the JDK, not the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need any special information placed in MANIFEST.MF a jarfile is just a zip file and you can use any zip tool to create the zip file and rename it afterwards.